# How to make classes like "Notification" class in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

Recently I've been learning about how to build Notifications in Android and I've come across this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.test_image)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentTitle("Notification Compat")
                .setContentText("Notification area --> 
                Modifiable!").setNumber(num);
```

Regardless of how I write the code, the result gives the same.
i.e For example, If I change the order, calling setContentText() before setContentTitle(). It returns the same Notification Builder object.
Code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.test_image)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentText("Notification area --> Modifiable!") // Modification
                .setContentTitle("Notification Compat").setNumber(num);
```

Can anyone tell me how is this possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Builder pattern. Each time you call a method of Builder it sets some value that you pass as parameter and returns the same Builder object. So the order doesn't matter. It is the same if you call setters methods without returning the object.
The sample code of the Builder:

```
public class Builder {

    String mTitle;
    int mCount;

    public Builder setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setCount(int count) {
        mCount = count;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
Builder builder = new Builder()
    .setTitle("Some title")
    .setCount(count);
```

Comment: Okay... Now, it makes sense... So, what happens after setting up the "mCount" with the value that is passed in through "count"? The Builder class constructor will be called and all the values that are specified are passed in it?

Comment: No, empty constructor is called once you create an instance of Builder (`Builder builder = new Builder()`). When you call the method the value is set and the same builder object is returned. Constructor isn't called.

Comment: So, the "return this" is used for this purpose? To, return the builder object?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) is an example how to create a `Builder pattern`.

**Example**

```
public class FooBar {
   private int mA, mB;

   private FooBar(int a, int b) {
      this.mA = a;
      this.mB = b;
   }

   public int getA() {
      return mA;
   }

   public void setA(int a) {
      this.mA = a;
   }

   public int getB() {
      return mB;
   }

   public void setB(int b) {
      this.mB = b;
   }

   public static class FooBarBuilder {
      private int mNestedA, mNestedB;

      public FooBarBuilder() {
          this.mNestedA = 0;
          this.mNestedB = 0;
      }

      public FooBarBuilder(int nestedA, int nestedB) {
          this.mNestedA = nestedA;
          this.mNestedB = nestedB;
      }

      public int getNestedA() {
          return mNestedA;
      }

      public FooBarBuilder setNestedA(int nestedA) {
          this.mNestedA = nestedA;
          return this;
      }

      public int getNestedB() {
          return mNestedB;
      }

      public FooBarBuilder setNestedB(int nestedB) {
          this.mNestedB = nestedB;
          return this;
      }

      public FooBar create() {
          return new FooBar(mNestedA, mNestedB);
      }
   }
}
```